# Странная реакция на добавление объектов и файлов в код сервера

Tags: c++, linux, boost, клиент-сервер

У меня есть клиент-серверное приложение на c++ под linux. Программа работатет и без проблем получает данные, но как только я добавляю объекты на сервер boost::property_tree::ptree или std::ofstream сразу же выдается ошибка вида: "recv failed: Bad address". С чем это может быть связано?

Мой код:

```
while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , (void*)msg , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
    //Send the message back to client
    std::cout << msg;
    //boost::property_tree::ptree heroTree; if uncomment - does not work
    //std::ofstream myfile; if uncomment - does not work
     write(client_sock , (void*)msg , sizeof(msg));
     }
    if(read_size == 0)
{
    puts("Client disconnected");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else if(read_size == -1)
{
    perror("recv failed");
}
```

Comment: А размер `msg` какой? Туда 2000 байт точно влезает? Т.е. не портите ли вы память в цикле.

Comment: write не гарантирует, что он запишет все данные, которые ему передали. Он возвращает кол-во байт, которые он записал.

Answer (score 2):

Увы информации мало, но скорее всего вы наткнулись на undefined behaviour. Если судить по приведенному коду, то возникает скорее всего из-за некорректной работы с `msg`.

1. Проверьте не удаляете ли случайно где-то `msg`, а потом используется удаленная память?
2. Размер выделенной памяти, на которую указывает `msg`, точно >= 2000 байт?
3. Строка `write(client_sock , (void*)msg , sizeof(msg));` выглядит сомнительной и корректна только в случае если `msg` статический массив. Либо вы хотите отправить адрес.

Если код не сильно большой, то лучше всего привести полностью, в крайнем случае выложить на [ideone](http://ideone.com/).